# Displaying data twice in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Date   Type   Amount
Jul-17 Type A 20
Jul-17 Type B 30
Jul-17 Type C 10
Aug-17 Type A 50
Aug-17 Type D 40
Aug-17 Type C 70
```

My query will only filters two month as below:

> SELECT DATE, Type, Amount  FROM Table 1 WHERE DATE >= '01-Jul-2017'
>   AND DATE <= '31-Aug-2017'

I want to display Type that does not exist in July and display amount 0 and Type that does not exist in August and display Amount 0 as below:

```
Date   Type   Amount
Jul-17 Type A 20
Aug-17 Type A 50
Jul-17 Type B 30
Aug-17 Type B 0
Jul-17 Type C 10
Aug-17 Type C 70
Jul-17 Type D 0
Aug-17 Type D 40
```

So far I have tried below, but it's affecting performance. I want to simplify the query without using union:

```
SELECT DATE, Type, Amount 
FROM Table 1
WHERE DATE >= '01-Jul-2017'
AND DATE <= '31-Aug-2017'

Union 

SELECT '01-Jul-2017' AS DATE, TYPE, 0 AS AMOUNT
WHERE DATE >= '01-Aug-2017'
AND DATE <= '31-Aug-2017'
AND Type NOT in (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE WHERE DATE >= '01-Jul-2017'
AND DATE <= '31-Jul-2017')

Union

SELECT '01-Aug-2017' AS DATE, TYPE, 0 AS AMOUNT
WHERE DATE >= '01-Jul-2017'
AND DATE <= '31-Jul-2017'
AND Type NOT in (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE WHERE DATE >= '01-Aug-2017'
AND DATE <= '31-Aug-2017')
```

Comment: Since you are showing only 2 months you could use pivot and display each month on a seperate column instead of row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross join to get all possible combinations and then use a left outer join to get the actual amount...

```
WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.Date ,
                    t2.Type
           FROM     dbo.Table1 t1
                    CROSS JOIN dbo.Table1 t2
           WHERE    t1.Date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-08-31'
                    AND t2.Date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-08-31'
         )
SELECT  cte.Date ,
        cte.Type ,
        COALESCE(t.Amount, 0) AS Amount
FROM    cte
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table1 AS t ON t.Date = cte.Date
                                           AND t.Type = cte.Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

At begininng I misred your tags, and thought you should do for MYSQL (apologize).  I leave MYSQL version at end.
I used * for brevity. Pls change it with full name list for your final query.

**THIS IS MSSQL VERSION**
You need to specify two dates just one time (at the beginning).
 I used TN as table name.

```
   WITH TT AS (SELECT *, MONTH(DATE) AS MN from TN WHERE DATE >= '2017-07-01' AND DATE <= '2017-08-31' )
    SELECT COALESCE(C.DATE, CASE WHEN C.MN2=MINMN THEN DATEADD(MONTH,+1, C.DATE2) ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,-1, C.DATE2) END)  AS DATE
    , COALESCE(C.TYPE, C.TYPE2) AS TYPE
    , COALESCE(C.AMOUNT,0) AS AMOUNT
    FROM
    (SELECT A.*, B.DATE AS DATE2, B.TYPE AS TYPE2, B.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT2, B.MN AS MN2, X.MINMN
    from TT A
    FULL JOIN TT B ON A.MN<>B.MN AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(MN) MINMN FROM TT) X
    )C
  ORDER BY DATE, TYPE     ;
```

Output:

```
    DATE               TYPE AMOUNT
1   17.07.2017 00:00:00 A   20
2   17.07.2017 00:00:00 B   30
3   17.07.2017 00:00:00 C   10
4   17.07.2017 00:00:00 D   0
5   17.08.2017 00:00:00 A   50
6   17.08.2017 00:00:00 B   0
7   17.08.2017 00:00:00 C   70
8   17.08.2017 00:00:00 D   40
```

**MYSQL VERSION**
At moment I just find this one (it use only one UNION, instead of two).
I used TN as table name.  Pls check it for performances.

```
SELECT * from TN WHERE DATE >= '2017-07-01' AND DATE <= '2017-08-31' 
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(A.DATE)=M1 THEN '2017-08-01' ELSE '2017-07-01' END AS DATE, A.TYPE, 0 AS AMOUNT
from TN A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TN WHERE DATE >= '2017-07-01' AND DATE <= '2017-08-31') B ON DATE_FORMAT(A.DATE ,'%Y-%m-01') <> DATE_FORMAT(B.DATE ,'%Y-%m-01') AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(MONTH(DATE)) AS M1 FROM TN WHERE DATE >= '2017-07-01' AND DATE <= '2017-08-31') X
WHERE A.DATE >= '2017-07-01' AND A.DATE <= '2017-08-31'
    AND  B.TYPE IS NULL
```

;

Output:

```
    Date      type  amount
1   2017-07-17  A   20
2   2017-07-17  B   30
3   2017-07-17  C   10
4   2017-08-17  A   50
5   2017-08-17  D   40
6   2017-08-17  C   70
7   2017-08-01  B   0
8   2017-07-01  D   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna execute the result using pivot.
You may try the below query:

```
select [Date] As Date_For_Table,
    [Type A] = 
    case
        when [Type A] IS NULL Then 0
        else [Type A]
    end,
    [Type B] = 
    case         
        when [Type B] IS NULL Then 0
        else [Type B]
    end,
    [Type C] = 
    case
        when [Type C] IS NULL Then 0
        else [Type C]
    end,
    [Type D] = 
    case
        when [Type D] IS NULL Then 0
        else [Type D]
    end
from 
(
select CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 120) as date ,type,Amount
from Table1
) as PivotData
pivot
(
avg(amount) for type in
([Type A],[Type B],[Type C],[Type D]))as Pivoting
order by date desc
```

output:
[image: Output]